# Create a schedule using a graph-theoretic model

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

*For the next Olympic Winter Games, the organizers wish to expand the number of teams competing in curling. They wish to have 14 teams enter, divided into two pools of seven teams each. Right now, they’re thinking of requiring that in preliminary play each team will play seven games against distinct opponents. Five of the opponents will come from their own pool and two of the opponents will come from the other pool. They’re having trouble setting up such a schedule, so they've come to you. By using an appropriate graph-theoretic model, either argue that they cannot use their current plan or devise a way for them to do so.*

I'm not entirely sure I understand what it's asking. I'm pretty sure I could draw a graph for this, but then it gets cumbersome with lots of lines extending from a single vertex--and I'm not sure it's even a graph at that point.

Comment: How many games shall be played between the teams of the same pool? Seven teams, each plays five games, each game counted twice...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Reference: This is Question 4 from Chapter 5 of [*Applied Combinatorics* by Keller and Trotter](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~trotter/book.pdf).

Use the Degree Sum Formula, which states that for all graphs

$G(V,E)$, $\sum\limits_{v \in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|$

This implies that "For any graph, the number of vertices with odd degree is even." (Corollary 5.2 in the book).

In a specified pool, each of the 7 teams must play exactly 5 others in the same pool. As a graph, each of the teams is a vertex with degree of exactly 5. This is impossible, as the number of vertices with odd degree is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Consider one pool of 7. the condition: *Five of the opponents will come from their own pool* is enough to see that the plan is not possible.

Lets the competitor be named from 1 to 7.

Assume with loss of generality that the opponents of 7 are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.
Notice that 6 has not choices for it's opponents. We are sure they are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Hence your are now left with the same problem but for a poll of 5 where you need de find 3 opponents for each.

I let you continue for the pool of 5 with the same argument and them for a pool of 3 and so on until you find a problem ;)

I hope it helps.